# Making first order linear equation into a system of linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have a parachute (skydiving) problem. The equation is
$$
mv' = -mg - kv
$$

as you can see this is a linear first order differential equation but my teacher want to use system of linear ODE to solve this analytically.

what i have tried:

making the the equation into second order

$$
m s'' = - mg - ks'
$$

and then from there

let $x_1 = s$ and $x_2 = s'$

we then can write $x_1' = x_2$

$$
m x_2' = -mg - kx_2
$$

and now i'm back to first order linear equation

i'm stuck here i don't know what to do am i even going at the right direction ?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes you are right . Your system is $x_1 ' = x_2$ and  $m x_2' = -mg - kx_2$ itself.

Comment: @Chinmayamishra where do i go from there ? do i just solve the $mx_2' = -mg-kx_2$ equation as a first order linear ode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system you are considering is :
$x_{1}' = x_{2}$
and $mx_2' = -mg-kx_2$ .
This is written as vector equation
\begin{equation}
{\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}' \\ 
x_{2}'  
\end{pmatrix} }=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & -k/m  
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} 
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
g 
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation}

Now Proceed.

Comment: isn't it supposed to be like this : 

\begin{equation}
{\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1}' \\ 
x_{2}'  
\end{pmatrix} }=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & -k/m  
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} 
\end{pmatrix} + 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
g 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: yes thanks for correction